# Find the entire functions that satisfy the following condition

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

the problem at hand is to find all the entire functions satisfying $|f(z)| = |z|^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

My attempt:
 $f$ grows at most as a polynomial of degree 2 therefore, it is a polynomial of degree 2.
Then $f = a_0 + a_1z +a_2z^2$

I'm sure i'm solving it correctly.

Any help would be awesome

Comment: apologies, I edited it out

Comment: @g.sassatelli Your deleted answer should work, if you fix the issue at $0$.  You can show the function and its first derivative both vanish.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I remembered the result to be true, then a doubt popped out, then I realised it's basically Morera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $z^{-2}f(z):\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb C$ is bounded and analytic. Therefore, it extends to an entire function $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$. Which must be constant by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: so the functions will be $f(z) = Cz^2$  where $C$ is a constant?

Comment: @HexaFlexagon Not *any* constant, but yes.

Comment: a constant whose magnitude is 1?

Comment: @HexaFlexagon Indeed.